# Angular/Typescript: write a factory returning types derived from base class

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, factory-pattern

I'm trying to write a factory method that returns classes, like this:

```
getWidget<T extends WidgetBase>(componentName: string): Type<T> {
    switch (componentName) {
        default:
            throw new Error(`Widget ${componentName} is not registered in the system`);
        case "Widget2":
            return Widget2Component;
    }
}
```

where Widget2Component is a classe defined in another file (Angular component) which derives from WidgetBase, and abstract class, and Type<> is an Angular interface defined like this:

```
interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T
}
```

The compiler complains:

Type 'typeof Widget2Component' is not assignable to type `'Type<T>'`.
  Type 'Widget2Component' is not assignable to type `'T'`.

but I don't get why... Widget2Component extends WidgetBase!

Comment: not really.....

Comment: My apologies, this is not the case for other language specifications, but it appears [you are correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Can_I_put_a_default_between_cases). However, due to misunderstandings like mine just now, it is convention to place the `default` at the end for clarity. As for your issue, my guess based on the available code is that `Widget2Component` cannot be `Type<T>` for every possible type `T`. Even though it extends `WidgetBase`, TypeScript is saying there are possible values of `T` that don't satisfy your constraint.

Comment: When you define a generic method what Typescript will enforce is the fact the for any `T` passed in the return value is in accordance with that `T`. Let's say I call `getWidget<Widget1Component>("Widget2")` which is a valid call under type rules. The value your function will return will be `typeof Widget2Component` when I asked for `typeof Widget1Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Titian is right in what he said in the comments...
So I modified my method to this:

```
getWidget(componentName: string): Type<WidgetBase> {
    switch (componentName) {
        default:
            throw new Error(`Widget ${componentName} is not registered in the system`);
        case "Widget1":
            return Widget1Component;
        case "Widget2":
            return Widget2Component;
    }
}
```